# Block an undesirable proxy from accessing a Rails 2.3.15 app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, proxy, block

I'm looking for a way to block a specific proxy, for example this one:

http://demosites.conversionsupport.com/reverseproxydemo?domainpath=http://stackoverflow.com

I don't want it accessing/displaying my rails 2.3.15 app on Heroku. I've played with the gems rack-rewrite and rack-block, but had no luck going that route because I need to block by domain name, not IP address (the thing is hosted on ghs.google.com, which I'd rather not block)

In a perfect world I could redirect to my canonical URL, but I'd also settle for a 503 or a 404.

(The reverse-proxy in question is used to show off the proxy owner's chat widget app, but on any website, instead of restricting use to sites owned by the proxy owner's potential clients.  It also causes some nasty crawl bot errors to be logged in google's web master tools.  That in and of itself isn't a big deal, but when coupled with that breaking-the-site-functionality thing, and the fact that my site has a Creative Commons license which requests the site not be reused for commercial purposes, it makes me want to put a stop to it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since none of the gems we mentioned above can be used with rails 2.3.15 (which I've since updated to 2.3.18), and I don't have the time to do the arduous upgrade from rails 2 to rails 3, I ended up going with the solution below.  (Note: this solution only applies to pages served from /app.  It does not apply to pages served from /public.  I'm still looking for a solution to protecting the pages served from /public.)

I dropped the bits of code below into /app/controllers/application_controller.rb

`1.2.3.*` is a placeholder for the block of IP addresses that I'm actually blocking. Replace `1.2.3` with the first three octets of the 0/24 range that you want to block, or replace `1.2.3.*` with a single ip address to block a single IP. You'll also want to replace `http://YourCanonicalDomain.tld/503.html` with the address of your 503 page, or other page you want to send users to so they can view your page at the URL it was meant to be displayed at, instead of leaving them at the reverse proxy's URL:

```
before_filter: block_ip
```

then later in the file:

```
def block_ip
      if request.remote_ip.match('1.2.3.*')
    redirect_to "http://YourCanonicalDomain.tld/503.html"
    return
  end
end
```

My 503.html, which resides in /public, displays a note to the user that they're trying to view content in a way that is not allowed, and that they'll shortly be redirected to the homepage for the site.  The 503.html contains this within the :

```
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="15;url=http://YourCanonicalDomain.tld">
```

Replace `http://YourCanonicalDomain.tld` with the page you want to redirect users to.  Raise or lower the number `15` to raise or lower the amount of time the page is displayed before the user is redirected.

Answer (score 0):

[Rack::Attack!!!](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack) seems quite thorough. I has [support for blacklisting](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack#blacklists), which sounds like what you need. It doesn't mention Rails 2.3 support, but you can configure it directly using your `config.ru` regardless.

The example given in the README, shows this

```
Rack::Attack.blacklist('block bad UA logins') do |req|
  req.path == '/login' && req.post? && req.user_agent == 'BadUA'
end
```

It looks like the [Rack request](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Rack/Request.html) (`req`) object is passed to the block so you should be able to use any of the methods available on that object.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but from what I'm seeing it looks like, as with rack-rewrite and rack-block, I could use rack-attack to block specific clients that are viewing my site via that undesirable proxy, but it doesn't have appear to have a way to check the full URL displayed in the browser's address bar and to rewrite or redirect or block based on the use of the proxy's URL instead of just mine.  Or am I perhaps missing something obvious that is staring me in the face?

Comment: I've updated my answer. I'm not sure if you could use the #referrer on the Rack request object?

Comment: Thanks for the new suggestion, but this is for a public site. The only logins are for admins. Somehow the bad proxy leaves no referrer entries in the logs at all.

However, I had an idea to try this:
http://demosites.conversionsupport.com/reverseproxydemo?domainpath=http://showmemyip.com

and discovered that it is reporting the IP address of that proxy, rather than the user's IP address as I'd mistakenly thought before.  I might be able to use rack-attack on this after all (if I can just figure out how to get them to work on the files in /public as well as the pages served from /app.)